# a square DIV element with an arrow on left side, keep it fixed

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a DIV with an arrow stay fixed.

Right now the content inside `arrow_box` decides where the arrow is.

How do I have it in a fixed position no matter what? Please run this code snippet to see what I mean:

```css
body {
width: 500px;
margin: 100px;
}

.arrow_box {
 position: relative;
 background: #88b7d5;
 border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
 right: 100%;
 top: 20%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
 border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
 border-right-color: #88b7d5;
 border-width: 10px;
 margin-top: -10px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
 border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
 border-right-color: #c2e1f5;
 border-width: 11px;
 margin-top: -11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow_box">
Hello
</div>
<br>
<div class="arrow_box">
Hello<br>
Hello<br>
Hello<br>
Hello<br>
Hello<br>
Hello<br>
Hello<br>
Hello<br>
Hello<br>
Hello<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the arrow fixed on the same position on every box? Simply replace `top:20%;` with `top:10px;` on `.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before`. Try this solution:

```css
body {
  margin:100px;
  width:500px;
}
.arrow_box {
  background:#88b7d5;
  border:4px solid #c2e1f5;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  min-height:50px;
  padding: 10px;
  position:relative;
}
.arrow_box:after,
.arrow_box:before {
  border:1px solid transparent;
  content:" ";
  height:0;
  pointer-events:none;
  position:absolute;
  right:100%;
  top:10px;
}
.arrow_box:after {
  border-color:rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-right-color:#88b7d5;
  border-width:10px;
  margin-top:-10px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
  border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
  border-right-color: #c2e1f5;
  border-width:12px;
  margin-top:-12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow_box">Hello</div>
<div class="arrow_box">
  Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
  Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
</div>
```